# Eductional Purpose: Why is Sensitivity and Specificity from Confusion matrix showing different results from my calculation?

Tags: r, self-study, accuracy, confusion-matrix

The definition of Sensitivity and Specificity from what I know are:-

***Sensitivity = (True Positive)/(True Positive + False Negative)***

***Specificity = (True Negative)/(True Negative + False Positive)***

Below is the R output for Confusion Matrix on which I am working:-

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

               Actual     
               0     1
 Predicted 0 35772 39494
           1 19757 94399

               Accuracy : 0.6872          
                 95% CI : (0.6851, 0.6893)
    No Information Rate : 0.7069          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               

                  Kappa : 0.3163          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          

            Sensitivity : 0.6442          
            Specificity : 0.7050          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.4753          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8269          
             Prevalence : 0.2931          
         Detection Rate : 0.1888          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.3973          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.6746          

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

So according to the above formula of Sensitivity and Specificity and using the values from the above show cross table of Predicted vs Actual,

Sensitivity = (94399)/(39494+94399) = 0.7050

Specificity = (35772)/(19757+35772) = 0.6442

Why is my calculated Sensitivity and Specificity does not match with the Sensitivity and Specificity output of the confusion matrix?

Comment: Because the R-function that you use defines "Positive" as 0 (see last line of your output), while you define it as 1.

Comment: Thank you very much.